# Visual Studio Database Project Script Domain Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, deployment, database-security

I am creating user creation script in an SQL Server 2008 Database Server project in Visual Studio 2010.

The script looks like this...

```
CREATE LOGIN Domain\User FROM WINDOWS
```

I will be developing on both my desktop PC and laptop. Neither run on a domain and use local users e.g. `DESKTOP\TestUser` and `LAPTOP\TestUser`.

What I need to do is to somehow inject a variable into the script that automatically sets the domain name. I believe in SQL Server this is `@@SERVERNAME`. Then I can work on both my PCs and the script will work. At present if I run it on say my laptop I get an error as `DESKTOP\TestUser` is not a Windows Principal on my laptop.

I have looked at the .sqlcmdvars files and I can set a variable in there that gets injected into the script. However I cannot seem to get this to something dynamic such as `@@SERVERNAME`.

I have also looked at running EXEC from my post deployment script but I get an error saying that this command is not valid in this context - I believe that means that EXEC is not accepted in the VS2010 DB project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to achieve that. It works for me well and creates a login for the local user:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'create login [' + @@SERVERNAME + N'\TestUser] from windows'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Good idea but sadly won't run as part of a DB deployment from visual studio. Gives an error "Only one statement is allowed per batch."

Comment: Maybe you should keep logins outside of VS (not in the db project). This is what we're doing.

Comment: Yes agreed. All of the objects can be in the DB Project and then you can run a permissions script afterwards. Thanks.